# magento 2 how to verify newsletter subscription?

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I have a "new customer account" page (magento 2) where there is the checkbox for subscription to newsletter.

How could I verify that this checkbox is linked to dotmailer and that it works?

I search about that but I didn't find anything that seems to be useful.

I have to say that I'm quite new to magento 2.

Thanks.